# Magento backend error notification does not display

Tags: php, magento

I have a small problem with Magento. I would like
to display a error notification in Magento to notify
a administrator if something went wrong with the 
execution of a module i have created.

The module is called at a specific time based on a 
cron expression.

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError('A problem has occured!');
```

This code gets called from the Model/Observer.php file. I have verified
that the function in which this code resides in is getting called with Mage::log()
but i still do not get any error notifications at the backend.

Does anyone have any clues what the problem might be?

Thanks in advance!